# iptables wget to google should be allowed and response should be blocked

Tags: iptables

I had tried numerous ways of using iptables, but all the time I see wget https://www.google.com is successful all the time..

I wanted to tcp connection (using wget) to google.com on 443 to be successful, but the file download (index.html) to be blocked. Please suggest.

Comment: Since the request and the response are all on the same TCP connection, iptables isn't the solution.  I can't think of an obvious way to do what you seem to want want, either.

Comment: I think what OP means is turning off Stateful Packet Inspection?

Comment: Or please suggest if there is a way to block the tcp acknowledgement when a file is uploaded from client..